# Can't find which *FILE* save the environment variable for cshell

Tags: environment-variables, csh

When I hit the cmd **set** in csh it shows me a list of env variables I have right now in my session.

I was wondering where they are set/saved and couldn't find the location.

I have tried in files **~/.cshrc** and ~/.cshrc.myusername and in both I saw none of the environment variables that set shows .

### Where are they?

Comment: There is no single file. Read the man page, specifically the initialization section. Not a programming question; voting to close.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7m71/index.html will perhaps link rot really fast.

Comment: @tripleee which forum is the right one to ask that?

Comment: My suggestion would be https://unix.stackexchange.com/ - you can flag for moderator intervention and ask for them to migrate this there.

Answer (score 0):

In memory. Each instance of csh will get a new copy of your default environment. Setting variables at the command prompt does not persist them anywhere for future sessions.